# GMP mpf_class precision lower than expected?

Tags: c++, precision, gmp

I'm trying to test whether GMP is working with the precision I want or not with the next program:

```
#include<gmpxx.h>                                                                                                                                     
#include<iostream>                                                                                                                                    
#include<iomanip>                                                                                                                                     


int main()                                                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                                     
    long prec = 1000;                                                                                                                                 
    mpf_set_default_prec(prec);                                                                                                                       

    mpf_class a(1);                                                                                                                                   
    mpf_class b(mpf_class(1)/sqrt(mpf_class(2)));                                                                                                     
    mpf_class t(mpf_class(1)/mpf_class(4));                                                                                                           
    mpf_class p(1);                                                                                                                                   
    mpf_class x,y,pi, pi2, sub;                                                                                                                       
    pi2 = mpf_class(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286);                                                   

    while ( a - b > mpf_class(1e-250))                                                                                                                
    {                                                                                                                                                 
        x = (a + b)/2;                                                                                                                                
        y = sqrt(a*b);                                                                                                                                
        t = t - p*(a-x)*(a-x);                                                                                                                        
        a = x;                                                                                                                                        
        b = y;                                                                                                                                        
        p *=2;                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                 

    pi =  (a+b)*(a+b)/(mpf_class(4)*t);                                                                                                               

    sub = pi - pi2;                                                                                                                                   
    std::cout << std::setprecision(80) << pi << '\n' << pi2 << '\n' << sub << '\n';                                                              

    return 0;                                                                                                                                         
}
```

It calculates pi with many digits and then substracts `pi2` (pi with 100 digits) from `pi` (value calculated, it's easy to check that all decimals shown are correct).

Output:

```
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286209
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
1.2246467991473531772260659322750010582097494459230781640628620899862803482534212e-16
```

The problem is that it's working with only 16 decimal places for `pi2` and I don't know why.

The code was taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=459229

I've tried different ways of initiating `pi2` but I can't manage to get more than 16 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `std::string` instead of number literal. Any value of the format aaa.bbb is treated as a double (limited precision) and with `f` suffix as float (limited precision again). In your case it is probably treated as double.

```
const std::string number = "3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286";
mpz_class pi2(number);
```

Comment: Or in C++11 you can write `3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286_mpf`.